# What are all the way that you try to make your code functional like?

Tags: programming-languages, concurrency, functional-programming

so that you can make your program concurrent easily in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I focus on making items Immutable.  Immutable objects allow you to reason about multi-threaded code a lot easier than "thread safe" objects.  The object has one visible state that can be passed between threads without any synchronization.  It takes the thought out of multi-threaded programming.

If you're interested, I've published a lot of my work with immutable objects, in particular immutable collections on code gallery.  The name of the project is [RantPack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/RantPack).  In the collection area I have

- ImmutableCollection<T>
- ImmutableMap<TKey,TValue>
- ImmutableAvlTree<T>
- ImmutableLinkedList<T>
- ImmutableArray<T>
- ImmutableStack<T>
- ImmutableQueue<T>

There is an additional shim layer which (CollectionUtility) which will produce wrapper objects that implement BCL interfaces such as IList<T> and ICollection<T>.  They can't fully implement the interfaces since they are immutable but all possible methods are implemented.

The source code (C#) including the unit testing is also available on the site.

Answer (score 1):

I program mainly in Java. I'm waiting patiently for the day where closures will be added to the language. But as I am still stuck on Java 1.4.2, even if they get added, that's not going to be for me for a long time !

That said, my main "functional" way of programming is making a lot of use of the "final" keyword. I try to have as many classes as possible completely immutable, and for the rest to have a clear distinction between what's transient and what's immutable.

Comment: +1 for the "final" - immutability is your friend. also you don't need to wait for closures if you use one of the functional JVM languages (e.g. Clojure or Scala) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use member variables or global variables. Use the local stack of functions/methods. When a method uses only internally scoped variables and call parameters and returns all information using out/inout/reference parameters or return values, it is functional.

Comment: You didn't cover it all: […] don't use I/O functions or functions that returns random value etc. Basically, don't use functions with side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Make everything asynchronic.
Use immutable objects, messages, etc.
Communicate via queues.

Comment: I can see how MQ help concurrency, but is that really functional ?

Comment: You're right, it's not functional, but it helps concurrency which is what I understand is the main goal here. Maybe I'm wrong and it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a talk on rubyconf 2008 about the subject, it's mostly ruby centered, but several concepts remain valid.

http://rubyconf2008.confreaks.com/better-ruby-through-functional-programming-2.html